# Backbone collection when is really triggered "update" event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the documentation:

*"update" (collection, options) — single event triggered after any number of models have been added or removed from a collection."*

When I fetch the collection for the first time I except "update" to be triggered because the models are added (because this is the first time).

But when I fetch the collection for the second time (to refresh the data) "update" is triggered again, even if no models are added or removed ("add" or "remove" events are not triggered). "change" event is triggered because some models attributes are changed.

My question is : **Is the backbone documentation incomplete and "update" is triggered even when "change" are performed on collection's models ?**

Or am I missing something ? (any clue for the mistake I could have done ?)

ps: I use collection **fetch** with no options and **parse** returns the models to add (first time) or refresh (second, third... fetch)

hope it's clear, thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this is a bug or incorrect documentation. Maybe it is your incorrect observation... proof or did not happen :)

Comment: when you are using collections in your past projects can you relate such things ? or is it behaving the way the documentation is describing it ?

Comment: after success fetch there is a `set` operation, which in turn triggers `update` if there were changes
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/27f7d41de1f64f6662a96f44531d7518953b1e07/backbone.js#L941

Comment: Yes I have seen that, so is the documentation wrong/incomplete ? Or am I not reading it right ?